# Using entity core framework 2.0.0, how do I specify the min attribute seen on the date type seen in asp.net core mvc model?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

```
[Display(Name = "Due Date")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }
```

Above is applicable code found in the model. In order to set the `type` to `date` I included `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` seen above. Otherwise, starting with asp.net core 2.0.0, they default to input elements of datetime-local type whereas previously they were just plain textboxes in .net core 1.x.

I assume I can add another line above `public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }` to specify the min attribute that will be populated in the views of my asp.net core application

What code looks like in view:

```
            <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="DueDate" class="pull-left"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="DueDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="DueDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Note that `type="date"` is only supported in Chrome and Edge - in other browsers it will just generate a standard textbox.

Comment: If your wanting to specify the minimum date that can be selected, you can add the `min` attribute in your view - e.g. `min="2017-08-26"` (you should also set the `max` attribute if setting the `min` attribute)

Comment: @StephenMuecke That would make sense if asp.net core views generated off of mvc models used raw html, but that is not the case. I've updated what the view code actually looks above for due date.

Comment: So what is the  problem? Is just `<input asp-for="DueDate" class="form-control" min="..." max="..."/>`

Comment: I am silly you are right. Please answer and I will mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is generating `type="date"` in the input which generates the browsers HTML-5 datepicker which also supports the `min` and `max` attributes.

You can modify your view to include those attributes, for example

```
<input asp-for="DueDate" class="form-control" min="2017-01-01" max="2017-12-31" />
```

to limit the date selection to this year. Note the `min` and `max` values need to be in ISO (`yyyy-MM-dd`) format, and that both should be used (the Chrome datepicker is a bit buggy if you do not include both)

Note however that `type="date"` is only supported in Chrome and Edge, and if your using IE or FireFox, then just a plain texbox will be displayed. I would recommend you consider using a jQuery datepicker plugin (e.g. `jquery-ui`) instead, so that your users have a consistent UI.